# Using php include with in a echo

Tags: php

I need to echo an php include. I have tried the below but neither work?

```
echo "<td>include'file.php'</td>";
echo "<td><?php include/file.php'?></td>";
```

Why doesn't this work and how can this be achieved?

Comment: stop down voting questions just because it is trivial. people need to learn from some where.

Comment: I can see how this question may appear a good one to newbies. Don't downvote it.

Comment: Could you read the tooltip that comes with downvote: `"This question does not show any research effort"`. I'm not sure how this question demonstrates any form of research effort. The manual page ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php ) clearly shows an example that is completely NOT like this code. ( It even has an example echo-ing a string, then including something, then echo-ing again)

Comment: @Nanne i am sorry you feel like that i have looked into this for quite a while. the reason why i did not find the answer by my self is that i an a novice and self teaching so i didnt know the right "terms" to search ... :/

Comment: @RickNash: Just relax, and think about this for a second: you're using `echo`, so you're already working _"in PHP mode"_. Why, then, would you need to use the opening `<?php` tag again? why wouldn't you just use an include statement, and echo any markup as a string, no PHP in the strings at all. That would make your code more readable, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DevZer0: that's not an argument and/or response to my argument. It does come quite close to an ad-hominem though? @ rick: no worries, it is not a personal thing, it is just the way this site works: to keep people interested, there is this voting thing trying to get the interesting questions more attention than other questions.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it does make sence, its funny i been on this issue for a while as soon someone points it out it becomes clear, i guess its the learning curve. thx

Comment: @RickNash I know it may be a little boring but [the documentation for strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (and the documentation in general) is really good and easy to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot start a new php block inside a php block.

You would probably do something like this:

```
echo "<td>";
include 'file.php';
echo "</td>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to `echo` included files, `include` means you are simply embedding the source code of `page1` in `page2`, if you `echo` on `page1` and you include on `page2` and if your `page1` has something like

`echo 'hello';`

This will be simply echoed on `page2` when you include `page1`.

So you need to simply use `include 'file.php';` that's it and use `echo` on `file.php`

Also, I would like to tell you that am sure you are doing something which is not usually done, like, why you need to include a file inside a just a `td` tag? Is that file used for some `string`/`int` output?

Comment: @Jimbo muhahaha :p thnx

Answer (score 1):

You're evaluating everything as a string. You need to do something like this.

```
echo '<td>', file_get_contents('file.php') ,'</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the include file returns something, then do it like this:

```
echo '<td>'.include('file.php').'</td>';  // highly unlikely though.
```

The more likely correct thing to do is this:

```
echo '<td>';
include('file.php');
echo '</td>';
```

If the included file is just text, then use `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
include 'file.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

This way the php will be evaluated and all output will be saved into a variable

Comment: Why make it more complicated? The OP is just getting their head around strings. One thing at a time.

Comment: The question was "Using php include with in a echo". If someone later on wants to know what the actual answer is to that, here it is.